# how do adjust right margin when increasing margin-left

Tags: css

I am styling a div that contains the main content of my web page.  The header has it's own div and correctly spans the page 100%.

I added a margin-left:125px style to the main content div and now the right edge exceeds 100% of the browser width.

How do I compensate for the this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure if its what you are trying to do, but:

```
    <style type="text/css">
        #Header {
            background: red;
        }

        #Content {
            margin-left: 125px;
            background: green;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="Header">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div id="Content">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
```

You don't need width:100%, because block level elements will automatically take all the width they can, unless specified otherwise.

Comment: my sample is not like this.
It is like so:
<div id="Header"></div>
<div id="Content"></div>

#content{margin-left:125px;}

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that you just don't need width:100%, does it?

Comment: Well something is making my content's right margin move beyond the browser width by the same value specified in the margin-left setting.

Comment: Then post your whole code already... Guessing is not that much fun -.-

Comment: You musn't mix width:100% with margin-left, or else the problem you mentioned will occur.